# Add remote javascript to prestashop 1.7

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop-1.7

I am having following issue with prestashop 1.7

1. I register static javascript with the hook `actionFrontControllerSetMedia`
2. I try to register dynamic remotely loaded javascript with the same method:

   - Of course it doesn't work as the `registerJavascript` expects local path.
   - `Context->addJs()` doesn't work for me anymore.

Is there any solution how to add javascript to the document?

Comment: same issue with addCSS ;(

Comment: as you see my newly marked answer, there is hope! :) 1.7.0.2 does indeed support it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/7022 (introduced in 1.7.0.2)

```
$this->registerJavascript(
   'remote-bootstrap',
   'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js',
   ['server' => 'remote', 'position' => 'head', 'priority' => 20]
);
```

Comment: man, you are my hero! Never thought of opening own pull request :) thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to add the JavaScript/CSS for all pages or for a specific page, you can use theme.yml to update it.
e.g. if you need to add following two external css on all of your pages. Add following in your theme.yml:

```
....
    css:
       all:     
         - id: fontawesome-css
           path: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css
           media: all
           priority: 200
           inline: false
           server: remote
         - id: googlecss
           path: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,500,600,700,800
           media: all
           priority: 200
           inline: false
           server: remote
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in any of your JS file, it will load the remote JS file:

```
function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'http://my.remote.js';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: this isn't actually the solution I was looking for ( as I was hoping for some native ps method ) but it would solve my problems and for the time being I can use it. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seem like it has been reintroduced in **1.7.0.2**  https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/7022
They will use **registerJavascript** and **registerStylesheet** instead.

```
$this->registerJavascript('remote-bootstrap-head', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js', ['server' => 'remote', 'position' => 'head', 'priority' => 20]);
$this->registerJavascript('remote-bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js', ['server' => 'remote', 'position' => 'bottom', 'priority' => 20]);
$this->registerStylesheet('remote-bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css', ['server' => 'remote', 'priority' => 20]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->context->controller->registerJavascript(
    'remote-openpay-js',
     'https://openpay.s3.amazonaws.com/openpay.v1.min.js',
     ['position' => 'bottom', 'server' => 'remote']
);
```